# Не обновляется PIP

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pip

Товарищи, помогите! Уже недели 2 парюсь
Начал устанавливать пакет через pip install и командная строка выдает:
    You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available и тд.
писал и python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        py3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        и через conda пробовал.
Все бесполезно. Что делать? Python 3.6 установлен

Comment: **pip3** попробуй так писать

Comment: Не фурычит. Пробовал

Comment: у вас по-видимому несколько питонов на машине установлено (и несколько pip соответственно). Убедитесь, что вы пытаетесь нужный pip обновить. `py -mpip --version` затем `py -mpip install -U pip`